# cannot get angular-marked to work against $scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that basically assigns text to a `$scope` variable like this;

```
$scope['Model'] = ["markdown text 1", "markdown text 2"];
```

And then I try to use `marked` on it within a view, like this;

```
<div ng-repeat="n in Model">
      <div marked="n"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div marked>
   <div ng-repeat="n in Model">
         {{n}}
   </div>
</div>
```

I just get `{{n}}` as the output, verbatim. Marked never runs, never does anything to it. I'm completely baffled. I know the text is fine.

I have tried all of the examples and nothing seems to work. It does work if I put in static, hard-coded text between `<marked>` directives - but nothing dynamic.

The only way I've been able to make anything work is to forcefully use the `marked(n)` function within the controller - which is far less than ideal and certainly not what I'm wanting to do.

After a lot of trying, I think that the way `angular-ui-router` is involved may play a part. Here is the HTML structure;

## index.html

```
<div class="content-body">
   <ui-view />
</div>
```

## content.html

```
<ui-view />
```

## entry.html

```
<div ng-repeat="m in model">
    <div marked="m"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the "use as a directive" guidelines look different in the repo's readme. either `<marked>bla</marked>` or `<div marked="scopevar"></div>`. could that be it?

Comment: No, I have tried all of those thoroughly.

Comment: It is like the text being output isn't really being treated as text, but something else. And I can't figure out why.

Comment: If I do `<marked>bla</marked>` it does work - it works if the text is statically, forcefully hard-coded into the HTML yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got it.

```
<div ng-repeat="m in model">
  <div marked="m"></div>
</div>
```

Works as per this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/q244srfh/

See, ng-repeat creates its own scope. So, you can bind the `m` variable to the `marked` directive.

I got it to work with `angular-ui-router` too: https://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/ck8by0ze/

Comment: sigh. No, that doesn't work either. I think it has something to do with the way I'm using `angular-ui-router`. It was only when I moved over to putting content in this `<ui-view>` that it started to give me new trouble.

Comment: Is the scope variable accessible at all then? This is new information btws, perhaps update your question

Comment: Yeah, I just updated it when I realized the part about `ui-router` might be relevant. I'm sure the scope variable is accessible, if I try to output it without using marked it works fine.

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that the availability of the scope variable is not the problem. I can output them fine without the `marked` directive. Unless there is some really special magic happening. But I just can't find anything that would suggest that.

Comment: The `<marked>` tags do seem to be flagged with `class="ng-isolate-scope"` - would that do anything to it?

Comment: Even if I don't use `ng-repeat`, I can't make it work. Just trying hard-coded `<marked="model[0]">` doesn't even work.

Comment: I dunno man, I'm running out of ideas. Updated my answer with an `angular-ui-router` demo.

Comment: This just does not make any sense at all.

Comment: :( no. I'm going to try rebuilding the entire project from scratch and cutting straight to the part where I need `marked` and see if I can catch some detail different.

Comment: check if you're using the correct controller / scope

Comment: thank you so much for all you've already helped with, as well.

Comment: The problem turned out to be an obscure typo in my `gulpfile.js` that was replacing an important part of the marked directive somehow.